# Codeigniter .htaccess redirect and hide URL part

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I wish to have two Codeigniter installations one in my default root `root/` and one in `root/en`. Problem is in my .htaccess file and in the location of default controller. Everything works in my default install, I have the default/front controller in the following directoy: `root/public/index.php` and my .htaccess looks like this in order to redirect and remove "public" from the url:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

ReWriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !public/
ReWriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule .* index.php?/$0 [PT,L]
```

Everything is fine in root, server automaticly redirects to `root/public/index.php` folder and reads "index.php" there, .htaccess then hides the "public/index.php" part of the url.

How can I write similar .htaccess file, so that when the user types the url "sitename/en" it automaticly redirects to `root/en/public/index.php` and hides the `public/index.php` part?

Comment: try editing #2 line to `RewriteBase /en`

Answer (score 0):

**try using any of the following :**

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /demo/
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

make sure config.php file has

```
$config['base_url'] = "http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']."/projectname";
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```